# VB.NET how can a jagged array be accessed as a single dimension array?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a jagged array; an array of Byte arrays.
I'm reading a chunk of data and then storing it in each array of the jagged array.
When done, I want write all bytes in the entire jagged array to a file in one operation, to avoid processing overhead of writing each array of jagged array.

Jagged array will contain 512 arrays or more.

Comment: Recursion of each byte-arrays in array, and each byte in each byte-array. Depending on what type of file you need to save (bytes to ascii? bytes to hex?), it might be enough to append byte-arrays next to each other or create a list of byte-arrays from array, or (metacode)array.tolist.tostring.

Comment: a jagged array *cannot* be accessed as a single-dimension array, because it *isn't* one; you could perhaps create an `IList<byte>` abstraction over them all, but... that won't help you in this scenario. To be honest, this sounds like an X/Y thing. If you just want to write them all: looping should be fine. 512 arrays is not unreasonable.

Comment: How about writing the data to file at the same time as you store it in the jagged array?

Comment: Andrew:  no time.  That thread has to immediately begin to receive the next incoming chunk.  A 2nd thread is responsible for 'simultaneously' writing previous chunk buffer to file.

Comment: @DougNull OK. Do be wary of using LINQ (e.g. SelectMany) if time is of the essence because it may well be slower than the "obvious" method of using a For loop - only timing the actual code will reveal if that is the case.

Comment: Andrew:  Can't write data to file until data has been received into a buffer to send to VB file write function.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.  Yes, I'm concerned that 'under the hood' VB is actually copying all bytes to a new, single dim array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten the jagged array of bytes arrays to a single array of bytes using `SelectMany`, and then write that single array to your file.

```
Imports System.Linq

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim a()() As Byte = New Byte(1)() {New Byte() {1, 2, 3}, New Byte() {4, 5, 6, 7}}
        ' Put all arays into a single array.
        Dim flatten As Byte() = a.SelectMany(Function(x) x).ToArray()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Robert, is the flattening fast (ie. doesn't copy) or does it actually copy all the bytes to a new array?

Comment: @Doug Null - Fast is always relative! `.ToArray()` creates a new array, but `SelectMany` returns an `IEnumerable`, so I guess you could use it to write directly to disk without creating an intermediate array.